# "je serais reconnaissant" et "je saurais gré" : différence ?

Tags: correspondance, registre-soutenu

> Je vous serais reconnaissant de me répondre à ce sujet.
>
> Je vous saurais gré de me répondre à ce sujet.

Ces deux formules de politesse sont-elles équivalentes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux phrases :

> Je vous serais reconnaissante de me répondre à ce sujet.

et

> Je vous saurais gré de me répondre à ce sujet.

ne sont pas strictement équivalentes.

On sait que la première est prononcée par une femme, information absente de la deuxième.

Comment: I slightly updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

La première phrase est correcte. La seconde nécessite le retrait de « reconnaissante » qui introduit une redondance.

> Je vous saurais gré de me répondre à ce sujet.

Comme ceci, les deux phrases sont équivalentes.

Comment: Je pense qu'il s'agissait d'une simple erreur de copier-coller.

Comment: @MathieuBouville: C'est fort probable mais je préfère le signaler pour des lecteurs non avertis.

Comment: I corrected the question. If you want you can update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Je vous serais reconnaissant de* est plus neutre, *je vous saurais gré* plus formel.  Je l''associe à un style épistolaire un peu guindé.

A l'oral, et à l'écrit aussi peut-être si *gré* est perçu comme un adjectif, *je vous saurais gré*, *je vous sais gré* sont parfois réalisés de manière fautive par *je vous serais gré*, *je vous suis gré* par des locuteurs natifs (c'est mon cas et souvent je dois y réfléchir à deux fois et me reprendre pour retomber sur *savoir gré*).